# For positive integer $n$, with $a$ and all $a_i$ prime to $n$, show that $\{a_1a,a_2a,\ldots,a_{\phi(n)}a\}=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{\phi(n)}\}\pmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A proposition related to Euler's Theorem

> If $n$ is any positive integer and $a$ is prime to $n$ then prove that,
>
> $\{a_1a,a_2a,a_3a,\ldots,a_{\phi(n)}a\} = \{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_{\phi(n)}\}\pmod{n}$, where $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_{\phi(n)}$ are positive integers less than and prime to $n$

Comment: Please show some of your work or explain where you are stuck. This is not a “Please do my homework for me” site.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin  yes you are right but I am not sure from where to start

Comment: Start by *stating* Eulers theorem.  Then consider the nature of the the set $\{a, a^2, a^3, .... a^{\phi(n)}\}\pmod n$.  How can this set compare to the other two sets.  You can do cases.  Those where $ord(a) = \phi(n)$ and those where $ord(a)=k < n$ but $k|n$.

Answer (score 0):

Call $A$ the set in question. You want to show that $A=aA$ whenever $gcd(a,n)=1$. Suppose $ax_1=ax_2\mod{}n$ then $n|a(x_1-x_2)$ and since $gcd(n,a)=1$ you have $x_1=x_2\mod{}n$. This shows that $f(x)=ax$ is an injection $A\to{}A$ which is a  finite set and thus it must be bijective. Surjectivity follows immediately.

Comment: But how does it proves my statement

Comment: You want to show that $f(x)=ax$ is surjective. By showing it is a bijection you have that information straight away

Comment: You want to say that these two sets have same cardinality but what about their relation

Comment: The residue classes $\mod{}n$ of coprime elements to $n$ form a group under multiplication and thus it is obvious $aA\subseteq{}A$

Comment: I am Confused....please don't use complex terms I am just a 9th grader

Comment: Proving $aA\subseteq{}A$ is straightforward anyway with just multiplication: can you show that?